# How remove a line of a string in Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove a specific line of a string using the replace.

If it is not possible with a replace, like some suggestion how i can delete a line, for example, my text have 3 lines, and i need remove line 2 or line 3... Why I can make this?

> this is my first line
>  and here this is my second line -> i need
>   delete this line
>  here is another line

```
replace( "and here this is my second line", WHAT I NEED USE HERE TO REMOVE THIS LINE );
```

Solution is use splice first and join after remove line:

```
var str="this is my first line\nand here this is my second line -> i need delete this line\nhere is another line";

ar=str.split('\n'); ar.splice(1,1); str=ar.join('\n'); // This remove line 2
ar=str.split('\n'); ar.splice(2,1); str=ar.join('\n'); // This remove line 3

console.log(str);
```

Comment: @dippas I highlighted the text as if it were a string

Comment: var str = "this is my first line
and here this is my second line 
here is another line";
var res = str.replace(and here this is my second line, "red"); , here I am replacing the line with red.

Comment: @AK1, thank you, but I like remove all line... 
imagine this line only starts with this value, then it may be different . So I need to delete the entire line and not change its value.

Comment: Something like this? `var str="this is my first line\nand here this is my second line -> i need delete this line\nhere is another line";var ar=str.split('\n');ar.splice(1,1);str=ar.join('\n');console.log(str);`

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: To "remove" the text, replace it with an empty string

Comment: @Ultimater yes, that is exacly what I needed! Thank you
But i don't understand the code. ar.splice and ar.join. I need learning more about this =) Great thanks!


If you want , you can create an answer to evaluate how correct = )

Answer (score 0):

Given that

```
var text = "";
text += "this is my first line\n";
text += "and here this is my second line\n";
text += "here is another line\n";
```

If you need to remove the first occurrence of the string use this:

```
text = text.replace("and here this is my second line\n", '');
```

And if you need to remove all the occurrences of the string use this one:

```
text = text.replace(/and here this is my second line\n/g, '');
```

Take into account that in the second example regular expression are used.
\n is the special character for line breaks and might be in different positions in your specific code

Comment: In case you want to remove the whole line text = text.replace("and here this is my second line\n", '');

Comment: Johny M. Salas M No, Because i don't  need replace, i need delete line.

Comment: In this case is being replace by an empty space, using \n allows you to remove the line break.

Comment: I'm try what you explain. But don't work... 
I create exemple in https://jsfiddle.net/klaveren/zL4hu0nu/
in return, i need delete 2 lines, telefone: and Contato: JULIANA. 
Each time, this information was change... I don't no if you understand me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the line by replacing the target line with an empty string.

`$(.someDivClass).text().replace("text to replace", "");`

However I don't think it would completely remove the element containing that text, if that's what you're looking for.

With standard JS, you use this snippet in a method and make some action trigger that event such as a button click:

```
if(document.getElementById("id of <p> tag").innerHTML == "specific text")
     document.getElementById("id of <p> tag").innerHTML = '';
```

I am not sure what your intentions are with removing the text and whether or not you want to completely remove the element containing the text, so this is the best solution I can offer. If you explain what your intentions are and how it will be applied to your project, I can provide a better solution.